# How to Run a Simple Python Script non-stop 24/7

Tags: python, bots, timeout

I have a simple python bot that I want to run non-stop 24/7. I haven't been able to figure out which GCP product would be best for this and how exactly I could set it up to work in this way. Any help or a detailed explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Deploy a VM on Google Cloud, ssh into your VM and put all the relevant code in there, then run your python bot as you normally would

Answer (score 0):

Although not a Google product, you should also consider [repl.it](https://repl.it):

It allows you to host for free (unlike GCP), 24/7 with uptimerobot constantly pinging it.

But, it is also a security problem. Others can easily see your code

Therefore, I think it is really about "security" and "price" (how confidential is the source code of your bot).